# Insert JSON string into the DB

Tags: json

i am trying to insert following JSON string in the Wordpress DB:

```
a:1:{i:6;a:3:{s:10:"product_id";i:6;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:8:"quantity";i:1;}}.
```

The string gets inserted,but like this:

```
s:81:"a:1:{i:6;a:3:{s:10:"product_id";i:6;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:8:"quantity";i:1;}}";
```

Then i tried with json_encode, but it is now inside quotes, which also breaks my functionality. So inside db i see:

```
"a:1:{i:6;a:3:{s:10:"product_id";i:6;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:8:"quantity";i:1;}}".
```

How to insert this string without " at the beginning and at the end?

Thank you

Comment: How are you trying to insert that?

Comment: it's not JSON string, it's object serialized with `serialize`. If you need json - use `json_encode` in a place of  `serialize`

Comment: Thanks guys for replying. Unserialize solved my issue. I was wrongly taking this as json, instead of serialized string. Yes, i feel embarrassed. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a:1:{i:6;a:3:{s:10:"product_id";i:6;s:12:"variation_id";i:0;s:8:"quantity";i:1;}}.
```

is not JSON, that’s a serialised PHP string. Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to unserialize it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. I was thinking about it as JSON all the time. I am not full time developer, so i guess that i am not that rich with knowledge. :)